# ffmpeg y4m to mp4 valid coding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to code y4m (raw) video to valid mp4 video. I was trying the following command, 
`ffmpeg -i INPUT.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 OUTPUT.mp4` 
It works fine but only play in chrome browser (html5 video player) and
In firefox it says "video can not be played because the video file is corrupted"
In safari it says 'loading...' and does not do anyting.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to the pixel format or atom placement.

Try

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.y4m -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart OUTPUT.mp4
```

Comment: Dear @Mulvya i tried your command but i still see that problem: http://filtersmart.com/neu/OUTPUT.mp4  Also i only can play this file with VLC. All others players say its corrupted.

Comment: Here is the y4m file if you want to check: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrqnomjt8ir7361/INPUT.y4m?dl=0

Comment: Ok, x264 is setting profile to `High 4:4:4` which most players don't support. Change `-qp 0` to `-crf 1`

Comment: Yes it works nice. but it seems lossy,  PSNR average:46.391661 min:45.742289 max:47.701176. I want y4m to mp4 without any loss of the quality. (PSNR=inf)

Comment: Lossless H.264 is not compatible with most players, as you have experienced.You can either switch to another codec like Quicktime Animation `-c:v qtrle` in MOV, or sacrifice playback compatibility, if you keep with H.264.

Comment: @mrana I am working on lossless video coding too and to be honest up to crf 5 the losses are  undetectable. The images could still be used for post processing without troubles. By the way how did you solve your initial problem? Using QuickTime Animation?

Comment: @RawBean i used `-crf 1` insted of `-qp 0` suggested by @Mulvya.
Is that what you mean by initial problem?

Comment: @mrana Yes, I just wish the community could see as accepted answer the one which solves your issue.

Comment: yes, that is partially solved of my problem, but i was searching a solution so codec y4m to mp4 with no loose of  the quality and supports of all player but that did not possible with ffmpeg or may be possible with `codec like Quicktime Animation -c:v qtrle in MOV`